# Insert data into the database from checkbox array using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, checkbox

I want to insert data into the database from checkbox[array] using Codeigniter.
My case is  User check assesmen criteria base from checkbox form, then my Controller process it when checkbox is check then value is 1, if uncheck then 0. Here is my view

```
ID | Trimester I | Trimester II | Trimester III |
21 | checbox_trimester_i[] | checbox_trimester_ii[] | checbox_trimester_iii[]
42 | checbox_trimester_i[] | checbox_trimester_ii[] | checbox_trimester_iii[]
23 | checbox_trimester_i[] | checbox_trimester_ii[] | checbox_trimester_iii[]
```

I want to insert into table ‘assesmen’. Here is my column in DB

```
ID | ID_pk | Trimester_1 | Trimester_2 | Trimester_3 |
1 | 21 | 1 | 0 | 1
2 | 42 | 0 | 1 | 1
3 | 23 | 1 | 0 | 0
```

Note * :

```
ID_pk = ID
Trimester_1 => checbox_trimester_i[]
Trimester_2 => checbox_trimester_ii[]
Trimester_3 => checbox_trimester_iii[]
```

Here is my View form:

```
foreach ($kuisioner as $art) { $no++; ?>
   <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $art->id ?>"></td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checbox_trimester_i[]">
        </td>         
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checbox_trimester_ii[]">
        </td>         
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checbox_trimester_iii[]">
        </td>
        </tr>
     <?php }
```

ScreenShoot View
[image]

Form View
[image]

Here is my Controller, but still not work, please help me to solve it. Thanks 

```
$posted = $this->input->post();
$as_trim_satu = isset($posted['checbox_trimester_i']) ? $posted['checbox_trimester_i'] : array();
$data = array();
  foreach($posted['id'] as $key => $value)
  {
    $info_user = array(
    'user_id' => $value,
    'trimester_satu' => in_array($posted['id'][$key], $as_trim_satu) ?1:0,
    );
    $data[] = $info_user;
  }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: In code igniter, you shouldn't be accessing $_POST directly. It providers $this->input class for dealing with them. To get a post variable, you use $this->input->post("field");

Comment: Like this ? $trimester_1=$this->input->post('checbox_trimester_i');$check = $trimester_1[$i] ? 1 : 0;

Comment: show us your view code along with how you are passing the values from js or form

Comment: I updated my question @Zeeshan, I added for View

Comment: Try to put a screenshot of your form also

Comment: Finish @Zeeshan, I added screenshot

Comment: ok thanks.I don't see any value set for your checkboxes and try

Comment: Okay , now I set value="1" for each checkbox, but If I check one, all output is 1. what's wrong with my controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123603/discussion-between-chris-and-zeeshan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to adjust your view like below to get correct values into the controller. If so, you can use the below code.

Give the name of check boxes like

```
name="checbox_trimester_i[<?php echo $art->id ?>]"
```

See the view I updated.

```
<?php foreach ($kuisioner as $art) { $no++; ?>
<tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $art->id ?>"> </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checbox_trimester_i[<?php echo $art->id ?>]" value="1">
    </td>         
    <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checbox_trimester_ii[<?php echo $art->id ?>]"  value="1">
    </td>         
    <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checbox_trimester_iii[<?php echo $art->id ?>]" value="1">
    </td>
    </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

Below is controller code to access the form data posted from page

```
if($this->input->post()){
        $data = array();
        $ids = $this->input->post('id');
        $checbox_trimester_i = $this->input->post('checbox_trimester_i');
        $checbox_trimester_ii = $this->input->post('checbox_trimester_ii');
        $checbox_trimester_iii = $this->input->post('checbox_trimester_iii');   
        if($ids ){
            foreach ($ids as $key => $value){
                $info_user = array(
                'user_id' => $value,
                'Trimester_1' => !empty($checbox_trimester_i[$value]) ? 1: 0,
                'Trimester_2' => !empty($checbox_trimester_ii[$value]) ? 1: 0,
                'Trimester_3' => !empty($checbox_trimester_iii[$value]) ? 1: 0,
                );
                $data[] = $info_user;

            }   
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
```

Please note the variable `$info_user` I have created. You may use your correct db column names before you update.