# Can't Get Checkbox value with post in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, checkbox

I've issue with checkbox in codeigniter. I Can't get Value from checkbox. I want to save only row cell with checkbox checked. So in controller I check whether the checkbox is checked or not. if checked save the data if not keep looking the checkbox with checked.

Please Help me to solve the issue. Thanks for your kindness

Best Regards,

### Dian

This is my screen shot [image: checkbox form]

This is my View

```
<div class="right_col" role="main">
        <div class="">
            <div class="page-title">
                <div class="title_left">
                  <h3>Jual Asset Form</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="x_panel">
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="x_content">
                            <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left"  method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('assettrn/jualasset'); ?>">
                                <div class="item form-group">
                                  <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="perush">Perusahaan</label>
                                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                    <select class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="1" name="perush">
                                      <option value="NULL"></option>    
                                      <?php foreach ($perushlov as $key => $value) { ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $value['idper']?>"><?php echo $value['namaper']?></option>
                                      <?php } ?>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>

                                   <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="lokasi">Lokasi Asset </label>
                                  <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <select class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1" name="lokasi">
                                      <option value="NULL"></option>    
                                      <?php foreach ($lokasi as $key => $value) { ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $value['idlokasi']?>"><?php echo $value['namalokasi']?></option>
                                      <?php } ?>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>

                                </div> 

                                <div class="item form-group">
                                  <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="kategori">Kategori </label>
                                  <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <select class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="1" name="kategori">
                                      <option value="NULL"></option>
                                      <?php foreach ($kat as $key => $value) { ?>                                           
                                        <option value="<?php echo $value['idkategory']?>"><?php echo $value['namakategory']?></option>}
                                      <?php } ?>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>

                                  <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="manufacture">Manufacture </label>
                                  <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <select class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="1" name="manufacture">
                                      <option value="NULL"></option>
                                      <?php foreach ($assetmanu as $key => $value) { ?>                                         
                                        <option value="<?php echo $value['manufacture']?>"><?php echo $value['manufacture']?></option>
                                      <?php } ?>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>
                                </div>     

                                <div class="item form-group">
                                  <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"  for="operan">Umur Asset</label>
                                  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                      <select class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1" name="operan">
                                            <option value="="> = </option>
                                            <option value=">"> <?php echo ">" ?>  </option>
                                            <option value="<"> <?php echo "<" ?> </option>
                                            <option value=">="> >= </option>
                                            <option value="<="> <= </option>
                                      </select>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <input id="umurasset" class="form-control col-md-1 col-xs-12" name="umurasset" type="text"></input>  
                                  </div>
                                  <label class="control-label"  for="umurasset">Tahun</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="item form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1">
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="view" value="view">View</button>     
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Header Jual -->
                                <div class="item form-group">
                                  <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="keterangan">Keterangan </label>
                                  <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <input id="ketjual" class="form-control col-md-1 col-xs-12" placeholder = "Required : Keterangan Jual Asset" name="ketjual" type="text"></input>  
                                  </div>

                                  <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="lokasi">Jual Ke PT </label>
                                  <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <select class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1" name="namaper">
                                      <option value="NULL"></option>    
                                      <?php foreach ($perushlov as $key => $value) { ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $value['idper']?>"><?php echo $value['namaper']?></option>
                                      <?php } ?>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>

                                </div> 

                                <div class="item form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1">
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="jual" value="jual">Jual Asset</button>     
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>

<tbody style="font-size: small">
                                                        <tbody style="font-size: small">
                                                        <?php $cnt; foreach ($asset as $key => $value) { ?>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><?php echo $cnt ?></td>
                                                            <td class="a-center ">
                                                              <input type="checkbox" class="flat" value = "<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>" name="sell[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]">
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td><?php echo $value['dpj_asset_perush']; ?><input type = 'hidden' name="dpjper[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $value['dpjper'] ?>"></input></td>
                                                            <td><?php echo $value['idasset']; ?><input type = 'hidden' name="idasset[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>" ></input></td>  
                                                            <td><?php echo $value['kodeasset']; ?><input type = 'hidden' name="kodeasset[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $value['kodeasset'] ?>"  ></input></td>
                                                            <td><?php echo $value['tglperolehan']; ?><input type = 'hidden' name="tglperolehan[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $value['tglperolehan'] ?>"  ></input></td>
                                                            <td><?php echo $value['umur_asset']; ?><input type = 'hidden' name="umur_asset[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $value['umur_asset'] ?>"  ></input></td>
                                                            <td><?php echo $value['namakategory']; ?><input type = 'hidden' name="idket[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $value['idkategory'] ?>"  ></input></td>
                                                            <td><?php echo $value['nama_asset']; ?><input type = 'hidden' name="nama_asset[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $value['nama_asset'] ?>" ></input></td> 
                                                        </tr> 
                                                        <?php $cnt++;} ?>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my controller

```
  public function jualasset()
    {  
        //$data['departement'] = $this->assetmodeltrn->mstdepartment()->result_array(); 

        if (isset($_POST['perush'])){
            $idper = $this->input->post('perush'); }
        else {
            $idper=null;
        }

        if (isset($_POST['lokasi'])){
            $lokasi = $this->input->post('lokasi'); }
        else {
            $lokasi=null;
        }

        if (isset($_POST['kategori'])){
            $ketagori = $this->input->post('kategori'); }
        else {
            $ketagori=null;
        }

        if (isset($_POST['manufacture'])){
            $manufacture = $this->input->post('manufacture'); }
        else {
            $manufacture=null;
        }



        if (isset($_POST['umurasset'])){

              $umurasset = $this->input->post('umurasset');
               echo  $umurasset; 
               if (isset($_POST['operan'])){
                    $operand = $_POST['operan'];
                    //echo $operand;
               } else {
                    $operand = null;
               }

            }
        else {
            $umurasset=null;
            $operand=null;
        }   


        //echo $this->$input->post('operan');

        if (isset($_POST['jual'])) {

        //Klik Jual Asset
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('ketjual', 'Keterangan Jual Asset', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('namaper', 'Name Perusahaan ', 'trim|required');


            $this->db1 = $this->load->database('default', true);
            $query = $this->db1->query("select nextval('assetjual_seq') header_id");
            $row = $query->row();


            if (isset($row)) {

                $header_id = $row->header_id;


                $loguser = $this->session->userdata('userid');
                $ketjual=$this->input->post('ketjual');
                $idper=$this->input->post('namaper');
                $creation_date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $creation_by=$loguser;
                $dpj_id = $this->session->userdata('userdpj_id');
                $approval = '1';


                $object_hdr= array
                    (
                    'header_id'=>intval($header_id),
                    'keterangan'=>$ketjual,
                    'iddpj'=>$dpj_id,
                    'idper'=>$idper,
                    'status'=>$approval,
                    'creation_date'=>$creation_date,
                    'creation_by'=>$loguser,
                    'update_date'=>$creation_date,              
                    'update_date'=>$creation_date,
                    'update_by'=>$loguser
                    );  

                $this->db1 = $this->load->database('default', true);
                $queryhdr = $this->db1->insert('tbljual_hdr',$object_hdr);

                $line =0;

                if ($queryhdr) {
                    echo 'Insert header Success ';
                    $object_dtl = array();
                    // Count distinct entries in the form
                    //$count = count($this->input->$_POST['tbljual']);

                    $chkjual = $this->input->post('sell');
                    $idasset = $this->input->post('idasset');
                    $kodeasset = $this->input->post('kodeasset');
                    $idper = $this->input->post('dpjper'); 


                    $records = array();


                    $num_of_rows=count($_POST)-1;

                    echo count($idasset);

                    $ids = $this->input->post('kodeasset');
                   if($ids ){
                   foreach ($ids as $key => $value){
                     $j = !empty($chkjual[$value]) ? 1:0;
                     echo '-' . $j  . ', ';

                  }
            }



                    }

                } else {

                    echo 'Insert Into Jual Detail Failed';
                }


            }


        } else {

            $dpj_id = $this->session->userdata('userdpj_id');
            $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
            $data['description'] = $this->session->userdata('userdescr');
            $data['group_id'] = $this->session->userdata('usergroup');          
            $data['deptname'] = $this->session->userdata('namadept');
            $data['perushlov'] = $this->assetmodel->perushlov()->result_array();
            $data['lokasi'] = $this->assetmodeltrn->lokasi()->result_array(); 
            $data['kat'] = $this->assetmodeltrn->listassetkat()->result_array();
            $data['cnt']=1;
            $data['assetmanu'] = $this->assetmodeltrn->listmanu()->result_array();
            $data['asset'] = $this->assetmodeltrn->assetjual($idper, $lokasi, $ketagori, $manufacture, $umurasset,$operand, $dpj_id)->result_array();
            $data['content'] = 'transaksi/jualasset';
            $this->load->view('template', $data);
        }

    }
```

This is the result :

[image]

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547458/insert-data-into-the-database-from-checkbox-array-using-codeigniter/39548973#39548973

Comment: Hi, I've change my code like on link you gave me. but it still it return 0, eventhough the checkbox is checked. please advise. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you paste your controller code here. seems that you have posted view code two times.

Comment: Also paste edited view code.

Comment: Hi, I've update my view and controller, I've not put anything in  my detail saving controller just echo to check whether it return the right value or not. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Still there are problems with your code.

**View Update**

1. Set value for the checkbox. See `<input type="checkbox" class="flat" value = "<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>" name="sell[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]">`
2. Other hidden element name should be index with a key. See the below updated view.

   ```
   <tbody style="font-size: small">
   <?php $cnt; foreach ($asset as $key => $value) { ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo $cnt ?></td>
       <td class="a-center ">
         <input type="checkbox" class="flat" value = "<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>" name="sell[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]">
       </td>
       <td><?php echo $value['dpj_asset_perush']; ?><input type = 'hidden' name="dpjper[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $value['dpjper'] ?>"></input></td>
       <td><?php echo $value['idasset']; ?><input type = 'hidden' name="idasset[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>" ></input></td>  
       <td><?php echo $value['kodeasset']; ?><input type = 'hidden' name="kodeasset[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $value['kodeasset'] ?>"  ></input></td>
       <td><?php echo $value['tglperolehan']; ?><input type = 'hidden' name="tglperolehan[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $value['tglperolehan'] ?>"  ></input></td>
       <td><?php echo $value['umur_asset']; ?><input type = 'hidden' name="umur_asset[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $value['umur_asset'] ?>"  ></input></td>
       <td><?php echo $value['namakategory']; ?><input type = 'hidden' name="idket[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $value['idkategory'] ?>"  ></input></td>
       <td><?php echo $value['nama_asset']; ?><input type = 'hidden' name="nama_asset[<?php echo $value['idasset'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $value['nama_asset'] ?>" ></input></td> 
   </tr> 
   <?php $cnt++;} ?>
   ```

**PHP**

You should loop through the checkbox not through the hidden fields. see the example loop here.

```
$ids = $this->input->post('sell');
if($ids ){
  foreach ($ids as $key => $value){
    $j = !empty($kodeasset[$value]) ? 1:0;

  }
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Hi,Thank you so much for your help.  I copy paste the code, but still it return 0 value. I don't know what I missed. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please updated your latest code here. So that I can check.

Comment: Hi, I've update the code. please help. thanks so much.

Comment: Seems that you are not looping through the `sell`. i.e  `$ids = $this->input->post('sell');` Please read the answer carefully and update your code as well. 

`$ids = $this->input->post('sell');
                   if($ids ){
                   foreach ($ids as $key => $value){
                     $j = !empty($chkjual[$value]) ? 1:0;
                     echo '-' . $j  . ', ';

                  }`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your kindness. I've update my code just like you write. but the error come out. Parse Error, syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in c:\wamp\www\asset_apps\application\controllers\assettrn.php on line 279. do you have any idea why this error come out? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Remove one extra `}` after `echo 'Insert Into Jual Detail Failed';`